# Copy metadata from one mp4 file to another in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4

I have a simple script for copying the exif (metadata) from one .jpg to another.

```
import piexif
import os

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        piexif.transplant(exifSrc, filename)
    else:
        continue
```

I now want to create a script that copies the metadata from one .mp4 to another. However, my programming skills are very limited and I can't even find a library (with documentation that I understand) to even start the project. I think ffmpeg can do the trick, altough I'm not sure.

Comment: this may help: https://pypi.org/project/tinytag/

Comment: or this: https://pypi.org/project/pytaglib/

Answer (score -1):

Use [`-map_metadata`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

```
ffmpeg -i origin.mp4 -i target.mp4 -map 1 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Note that a new output file must be made as `ffmpeg` cannot perform in-place editing.